# Codeigniter and the big picture

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

Have recently started using Codeigniter and have gotten through most of the tutorials. I'd like to convert a smallish PHP/MySQL website to run entirely on the CI framework. The code is four years old, written in PHP4, and is a mess. I don't mind rewriting all of it.

The problem I'm having is find the 'right' solution to this problem.  I'd like to keep the code as OOP/PHP5 as possible, and as clean as possible as well. The website has five six main components arranged in to DIVs.  Two stack to form a center column, one left, one right, one header/menu, and one dynamically filled Fancybox.  The current index.php simply calls header.php, then goes on to `<div class="class1"><include ('box1.php')</div>` and so on.

The codeigniter examples I've seen use `$this->load->view('header')` and footer on each template file to get the structure set up.  This seems to be a redundant and messy way to handle the header, loading of the CSS file, etc.

What is the proper way to get these controllers and associated views loaded?  The codeigniter version of a 'wrapper', if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get a template library, i personally prefer working with either of [Colin Williams](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/165780/) or [Phil Sturgeons](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2009/12/CodeIgniter-Template-library).

in essence, you do something like this: (assuming "layout" is your HTML template)

**layout.php (view)**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title><?=$title;?></title>
  <?=$metaData;?>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="left">
    <?=$leftContent;?>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <?=$main;?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

then in your controller:

**site.php (controller)**

```
class Site extends Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
      $this->load->library('template');
      $this->template->set_layout('layout');
  }

  function index()
  {
      $this->template->write_region('title', 'This is my title');
      $data['somedata'] = 'foo'
      $this->template->write_region('main', 'My content', $data);
      $this->template->render();
  }
}
```

This will output your data in to your template, without needing to have load views each time etc.

My syntax is a little off, so check library specific docs for the correct code, but template libraries are the way to go imo.

Comment: I continued to research the subject and had narrowed it down to either using a template library, or calling a view script from another view script, which seemed a bit dodgey. Thanks!

Comment: it's perfectably acceptable to call a view from within a view. having a "header" view, and a "navigation" view could be extremely useful. MVC perfectionists would disgree, but code like `if($foo=='bar') { $this->load->view('baz'); } else { $this->load->view('bam'); }` in a view can be a huge time saver and simplifier. MVC=concept!